# Will Hibernate criteria results update during a single transaction without session flush?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence

For whatever reason I have a code that in essence does something like below: it loads an instance a couple of times in a single transaction/session:

```
@Transactional
public void fun(final String someName){
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) session()
                    .createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("name", someName))
                    .uniqueResult();

        // when not found
        if(someClass == null){
           someClass = new SomeClass();
           someClass.setName(someName); // it SHOULD be found in subsequent criteria calls
       }

        process(someClass);

        session().saveOrUpdate(someClass);
        // session.flush();                     // should it be here?
    }
}
```

What I am not sure about is if the results of the `session().createCriteria...` call change during the loop.

It's in a transaction, and if I don't find an entity - I create it (but only once).

So during the second pass, will `someClass` instance ALWAYS be non-null?

Comment: Without more code we can only guess, maybe the `flush`was there to prevent OOM, maybe `someName` is changed as a side effect of `process`and you are creating 10 new entities... maybe this is just a bad sample of you you should not write retries. When `someName`is not a `final` member and is changed somewhere, then most likely the result of your query will change.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the code; assume `someName` is final. Assume this is all there is - transaction operates on a single `SomeClass` but loads/saves it mulitple times (because of the design pattern - chain of responsibility / decorator / something like this...)

Comment: then the criteria retrieves the entity from your first-level cache even if you did not call flush, as long as you stay in the same session. No need to call flush.

Comment: @Andreas thank you. But what you are saying is quite the opposite of what **edubriguenti** wrote below. Can you confront? I want to accept a correct answer ;-)

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/objectstate-flushing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you do not have to call flush, you should rarely execute flush. However the best way to proof something is with a straightforward demo, therefore I wrote a Spring Boot/Data sample and pushed it to [Github](https://github.com/AndreasKl/samples_for_stackoverflow/tree/master/hibernatesample). The code is equivalent to yours, and uses Hibernate 4.3.5:

```
@Transactional
public void createOrUpdateEmployee(String firstName, String lastName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Employee employee = repository.findByLastName(lastName);
    if (employee == null) {
      employee = new Employee(firstName, lastName);
      if (i > 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This can never happen!");
      }
    }

    log.info(employee);

    repository.save(employee);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
....350  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=0, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....396  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....401  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....403  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....405  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....407  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....410  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....412  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....427  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
....429  ...EmployeeService      : Employee [id=1, firstName=Andreas, lastName=Kluth, hashCode=1686333223]
```

As I would have expected the entity is retrieved from the L1 cache (hashCode stays the same) and automagically flushed as the already mentioned documentation link points out: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/objectstate-flushing.html

Comment: Thank you. Also an important part here is a good equals hashCode, right?  Or, will the Java's default implementation (identity) work?

Comment: @NaariomMet This highly depends on your needs, I often use the default hashCode/equals and if it's needed implement a solution on business keys. https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode There are more complex tries to solve this e.g. via special annotations and reflections etc.

Comment: @Andreas ok, I don't need a custom hashCode / equals in `SomeClass`. But will the default impl. give the behavior you described in your answer? i.e. no need for flushing, becaue (...)

Comment: @NaariomMet Yes this behavior works even if you do not implement hashCode/equals, you can find the whole sample on github: https://github.com/AndreasKl/samples_for_stackoverflow/blob/master/hibernatesample/src/main/java/net/andreaskluth/hibernatesample/Employee.java the used entity.

Answer (score -1):

Every time your code pass here:

```
 SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) session()
                    .createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("name", someName))
                    .uniqueResult();
```

`someClass` will be null or have a reference to a registry in your database.

*(I'm assuming that  `.add(Restrictions.eq("name", someName))` always return an unique result, otherwise it will throw an exception)*

If you are  creating objects that have different `@ids` here   `process(someClass);` then you don't need to worry.

I normally use **flush**, when the database generate the **id dynamically**, and I need the object to reflect it right now (for example, a sequence id), so I can use it.

But in your case, I think you are providing different `ids` to the `someClass`, in the `process` method, so you don'need to worry about flushing.

---

**EDITED**

Opsss...

I didn't see this line

> // it SHOULD be found in subsequent criteria calls

Assuming this, **you should flush**. So the database will reflect your new registry, otherwise, only at the end of the whole transaction all registries would be seen.

---

**Another thing:**

If this is the real code, you should do this:

```
SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) session()
.createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("name", someName))
.uniqueResult();

for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
```

This way you don't need to go to the database at each iteration, assuming you are searching for the same object. (The first level cache can help here, but if you know it's the same object you are getting, just let it outside the loop).

Comment: Thank you. I should flush even when I'm loading it from criteria in the same transaction? What about L1 cache?

Comment: Well, the loading of entity INSIDE the loop is the essence of this question ;-)

Comment: So, the question is: If save is done to an object, will it already be added to the first level cache and the same transaction can find it using uniqueResult() ?

Comment: Yes, sort of. If the criteria are the same (or sequence of different criteria), then the same instance will be found AND AFTER the transaction end (commits) flushed to the DB (with the state it had after LAST iteration). correct?

Comment: Yes. Perfect. That's it. My only doubt is in this case: You didn't find the entity. So a new one is created, and you save but don't flush. Will The next hibernate call find the entity you just created? I'm not sure.